# Show all data from the second table overriding with the same data in the first table

Tags: mysql

I would like to get the `user_settings` fields (that are in the `default_settings`) and the `default_settings` fields that don't exists in the `user_settings`. As per result below

default_settings

| field | value |
| --- | --- |
| Name | Test |
| Age | 21 |
| Sex | M |
| Dob |  |

user_settings

| field | value |
| --- | --- |
| Name | Jack |
| Age | 40 |

result =>

| field | value |
| --- | --- |
| Name | Jack |
| Age | 40 |
| Sex | M |
| Dob |  |

```
SELECT ds.field, ds.value
FROM user_settings AS us
LEFT JOIN default_settings AS ds ON ds.field != us.field
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write it this way:

```
SELECT ds.field, COALESCE(us.value, ds.value) AS value
FROM default_settings AS ds
LEFT JOIN user_settings AS us ON ds.field = us.field;
```